# Python Turtle Rectangle Using 2 Corner Coordinates

Tags: python-2.7, turtle-graphics

beginning CS student here. I am trying to have python 2.7 draw a rectangle using a function that only has the turtle object, the upper left corner coordinates, and the lower right corner coordinates as arguments. I know there are simpler way of drawing a rectangle but I am trying to do it only using corner coordinates.

After running my current code I get the following:

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

I know this is probably something simple but I am having trouble figuring out what I'm doing wrong so any help would be appreciated.

My code is as follows:

```
from turtlegraphics import Turtle

def drawLine(t1,x1,y1,x2,y2):
    t1.setWidth(1)
    t1.setColor(0,0,0)
    t1.up()
    t1.move(x1,y1)
    t1.down()
    t1.move(x2,y2)

def rectangleSimple(t2,upperLeftPoint,lowerRightPoint):
    t2.setWidth(1)
    t2.setColor(0,0,0)
    t2.up()
    t2.move(upperLeftPoint)
    t2.down()
    t2.setDirection(270)
    t2.move(lowerRightPoint[2])
    t2.setDirection(0)
    t2.move(lowerRightPoint)
    t2.setDirection(90)
    t2.move(upperLeftPoint[2])
    t2.setDirection(180)
    t2.move(upperLeftPoint)

def main():

    t1 = Turtle()                       
    x1 = 0
    y1 = 0
    x2 = 50
    y2 = 0

    drawLine(t1,x1,y1,x2,y2)

    t2 = Turtle()
    upperLeftPoint = (-100,50)
    lowerRightPoint = (100,-50)

    rectangleSimple(t2,upperLeftPoint,lowerRightPoint)


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the `turtle` module, not `turtlegraphics` but my guess is these two lines are at issue:

```
t2.move(lowerRightPoint[2])
t2.move(upperLeftPoint[2])
```

Your *Point variables are tuples with two values, X & Y, at indexes 0 & 1 but you're accessing the non-existent third value at index 2.  There are many different ways to implement what you're trying to do, here's one using the `turtle` module that comes with Python:

```
from turtle import Turtle

X, Y = range(2)

def drawLine(t, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    t.up()
    t.width(1)
    t.pencolor(1, 0, 0)  # red
    t.goto(x1, y1)
    t.down()
    t.goto(x2, y2)

def rectangleSimple(t, upperLeftPoint, lowerRightPoint):
    t.up()
    t.width(1)
    t.pencolor(0, 1, 0)  # green
    t.goto(upperLeftPoint)
    t.setheading(0)  # East
    t.down()
    t.goto(lowerRightPoint[X], upperLeftPoint[Y])
    t.right(90)
    t.goto(lowerRightPoint)
    t.right(90)
    t.goto(upperLeftPoint[X], lowerRightPoint[Y])
    t.right(90)
    t.goto(upperLeftPoint)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    from turtle import done

    t1 = Turtle()                       

    drawLine(t1, 0, 0, 50, 0)

    t2 = Turtle()
    upperLeftPoint = (-100, 50)
    lowerRightPoint = (100, -50)

    rectangleSimple(t2, upperLeftPoint, lowerRightPoint)

    done()
```

Comment: Thank you, my apologies for making such an elementary mistake -_-